# Script to retrieve OU settings

Tags: google-admin-settings-api, google-admin-audit-api

Does someone have a script that will go thru the OUs in Google Admin and return the settings for each group and subgroups?
I am looking for an easy way to compare the settings on multiple OUs.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units#get_ou), to retrieve an organizational unit, use the following `GET` request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing). The `orgUnitPath` query string is the full path for this organizational unit. For the request and response properties, see the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/get.html).

If you are an administrator retrieving an organizational unit, use `my_customer`.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/orgunits/orgUnitPath
```

If you are a reseller retrieving an organizational unit for a resold customer, use the customerId. To get the customerId use the [Retrieve a user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) operation.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customerId/orgunits/orgUnitPath
```